# Form Issue with Wordpress

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm a beginner at code and having trouble figuring out why my form looks so stretched. http://mycolorshop.com/mycolorshop-inc/contactus

I thought it was the margins, so I increased it. I thought it was the width, so I put them at 50%. Neither worked. Can someone tell me what I need to change please?

Here is the code:

```
/* Custom Widget - Contact Form */
.wpcf7-form p { 
    margin-bottom: 50px; 
}
.wpcf7-form input {
    width: 50%;
}
.wpcf7-form input[type="submit"] {
    width: inherit;
    padding: 50px 30px;
}
.wpcf7-form textarea {
    height: 94px;
    min-height: 68px;
}
.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-response-output {
    margin-left: 20;
    margin-right: 20;
}
.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: -60px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#footer .wpcf7-form input,
#footer .wpcf7-form textarea {
    color: #B53D85;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    background: #B53D85;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -ms-border-radius: 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#footer .wpcf7-form input[type=submit] {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border: 20px solid #111;
    background: #B53D85;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The centering code worked, thanks optimus! The other one didn't do anything. Do you know how I can get a colored box under it,  to make it stand out?

Comment: You could do something like this:

    form ( width:50%; margin:0 auto; border-bottom:5px solid #f00; }

Comment: It is there. The color is just too similar. You can see by this revised code:

.form { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border-bottom: 5px solid #000; padding-bottom: 25px; }

Comment: I chose a light cream color. I used the code you suggested and its just making a thin bar under the submit button. Maybe its because it thinks just to color the bottom border?

Comment: Didn't you just want a box under the form? "colored box under it"

Comment: Oh no sorry, I didn't explain it well. I was wondering how to put a colored box behind the entire form only to set it apart from the page.